# Disable some characters from input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have found some instructions similar, but none helps, all of them are either for special chars or for digits.

I need to make user type only 1 , 2 , 3, 4, 5, N, O, A, B, C . all other characters should be restricted.

Any way I can make my own selection of restricted/allowed chars for inputs ?

- Not very familiar with javascript.

Comment: `all of them are either for special chars or for digits.` Can't you just modify the code, rather than just blindly copy and paste?

Comment: use http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/limitkeypress

Comment: new link for limitkeypress http://brianjaeger.com/process.php

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(function(){
  $('#txt').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 97 || e.which == 98 || e.which == 99 || e.which == 110 || e.which == 111 || e.which == 65 || e.which == 66 || e.which == 67 || e.which == 78 || e.which == 79 || e.which == 49 || e.which == 50 || e.which == 51 || e.which == 52 || e.which == 53){
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='txt' value='' onpaste="return false" />
```

**Update 9th March 2018**

```js
$(function(){
  $('#txt').keypress(function(e){
    // allowed char: 1 , 2 , 3, 4, 5, N, O, A, B, C
    let allow_char = [97,98,99,110,111,65,66,67,78,79,49,50,51,52,53];
    if(allow_char.indexOf(e.which) !== -1 ){
      //do something
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='txt' value='' onpaste="return false" />
```

**Update 25th November 2020**

```
let textarea = document.getElementById('txt');

textarea.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if(['1','2','3','4','5', 'N', 'O', 'A', 'B', 'C'].indexOf(e.key) !== -1){
    // do something
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/pintu1611/pen/VwKZrKJ)

Comment: Doesn't work with chars created with modifiers pressed, does it?

Comment: Modifiers like shift and alt keys. Having them pressed can result in different characters - depending on the key, but the `event.keyCode` will be the same.

Comment: You can shorten the code by using `[97,98,...].indexOf(e.which) != -1`

Comment: This is the wrong way to go at it.  It does not prevent pasting bad characters in the field.

Comment: e.which is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy, Thank you for the update, I have updated the code

Answer (score 31):

without JQuery

```
document.getElementById("foo").onkeypress = function(e) {
    var chr = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if ("12345NOABC".indexOf(chr) < 0)
        return false;
};
```

For one liners, from @mplungjan and @matthew-lock's comment

```
document.querySelector("#foo").onkeypress = function(e) {
    return "12345NOABC".indexOf(String.fromCharCode(e.which)) >= 0;
};
```

Comment: or even `return "12345NOABC".indexOf( String.fromCharCode(e.which) ) >= 0;` to reduce it to one line

Comment: This is the wrong way to go at it.  It does not prevent pasting bad characters in the field.

Comment: What is the right way then?

Comment: @rdb To disable paste,  add  `onpaste="return false;"` to input tag.

Comment: Why would you disable paste? That would be a big accessibility problem. Handle the input event instead.

Answer (score 6):

It's not 100% clear whether you want to restrict the form being submitted with invalid values, or literally prevent the user from even typing those values. The other answers deal with the latter, and I think that *is* what you meant, but there will be people arriving here (like me) who just want to prevent form submission.

In which case:

Use the `pattern` attribute on the `input` element:

```
<input pattern="[REGEX HERE]">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable a few characters from input field you can do something like that:

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=86);"/>
```

86 is the code for V. Check code for other keys from the following link.

https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: How does this differ from [Pragnesh Chauhan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14806389/3789665)?

Answer (score 2):

html

```
<input type="text" name="" value="" id="testr">
<script type="text/javascript" src="testkeydown.js"></script>
```

javascript

```
document.getElementById('testr').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    const regex = RegExp('[0-9a-zA-Z]');

    if (!regex.test(e.key) && e.key != 'backspace') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

In the code example above here you see a piece of code that disables most characters that are not between 0-9, a-z, A-Z in plain js.

If you like to research it more you can google mdn keydown event and look for the Morzilla developer network.

Comment: A little improvement so backspace shift delete can be used: (!regexVehiclePlate.test(e.key) && e.key.length == 1)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking for pure js solution:
You need to prevent the key for the onkeydown event just like this

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="" value="" onkeydown="preventSomeKeys(event)">
```

Javascript

```
function preventSomeKeys(event){
  var keyCode = event.keyCode
  if([97,98,99,110,111,65,66,67,78,79,49,50,51,52,53].includes(keyCode)){
     return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use the pattern attribute

It won't prevent the user to enter an unwanted character, but when they submit the form, there'll be a neat error message you can even customize. See this code below:

```
<input pattern="[1-5A-CNO].*" title="You can only use the following characters: 1 , 2 , 3, 4, 5, N, O, A, B, C">
```

Source / sandbox to try it out:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that is more robust and prevents things like pasting in invalid characters:

```js
let saved = ""
let input = document.getElementById("in")
input.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  saved = input.value
})
input.addEventListener('input', () => {
  if (!/^[0-9]*$/.test(input.value)) {
    console.log("invalid input!!")
    input.value = saved
  }
})
```

```html
<input id="in" type="text" leng/>
```

In this example I have prevented any non-numeric characters from being entered in