# Disable keys in HTML textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code for my `form`.

```
<tr> 
            <td>Nombre:</td> 
            <td><input type="text" name="company" autofocus id="company"/></td> 
</tr>
```

So would like to disable some keys in this input as V, C, any key.

It´s possible?

Comment: Yes . its Possible.

Comment: Let me know, the safer way to do it; an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable some characters from input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806200/disable-some-characters-from-input-field)

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible. You can disable keys in the input tag. Try the under given code.

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=86);"/>
```

86 is the code for V. In this way you can disable keys on your input. Follow the under given link to check codes for other keys as well.

https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to `keydown` event and prevent `input` if your key is forbidden:

```js
const i = document.getElementById('company');

i.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (['C', 'V'].includes(e.key)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" name="company" autofocus id="company"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just a sample code to prevent those keys. you may use as it your need.

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 67||e.keyCode === 86) {  //C, V will be disabled.
            e.preventDefault();
             alert('not allowed');
        }
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use HTML5 you can use the `pattern` attribute
This contains a Regular Expression with the rules you want.

My example does not use JavaScript, but do can solve your problem

Like this example:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  Country code: <input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" title="Three letter country code">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This will accept only a three letter country code